# Python~Weekly time of day/week monitor

Tags: python, email, timer, cron

The basic concept of what i'm trying to do:

I want it to Check if it's 2-5pm and Sunday {every-{2 hours}
if True it should continue to the bottom of the script(which emails me my servers status) and in 36 hour's to reset the timer/it's active search to see if its Sunday at 2-5 pm

I've seen a few different methods for timers but i couldn't find one that actively scan's to see if it's the specified time(in this case it'd be ideal if it checked if it was 2-5pm on a Sunday every 2 hour's)

Any Help would be greatly Appreciated
Respectfully,
Jame's

Edit:
 Got it outputting information right after i reposted, just had to add the time module lol :P

Script so far i havent implemented the .py launching portion yet but ill update the post when i get that going forsure.

```
import datetime
import croniter
import crontab
import time

c = croniter.croniter("0 20,21,22 * * SUN")
next_due_date = c.get_next(datetime.datetime)

print c.get_next(datetime.datetime)

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now > next_due_date:
        do_something()
        time.sleep(60 * 60 * 36)
    else:
        time.sleep(60 * 60 * 2)
```

Edit2: My attempt at adding the file path: results in a keyerror

```
import datetime
import croniter
import crontab
import time

c = croniter.croniter("0 20,21,22 * * SUN ./line.py")
next_due_date = c.get_next(datetime.datetime)

print c.get_next(datetime.datetime)

while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now > next_due_date:
        do_something()
        time.sleep(60 * 60 * 36)
    else:
        time.sleep(60 * 60 * 2)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: right now im just looking up some of the command's he used it take's me a little bit to get going, I've only start a few days ago :P but i have a wee bit of experience in other languages so it translates relativity well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do, however, as far as I understand, it seems that using a cron task would be adequate.

Do you want to start your script on sunday 2PM? If yes, then a crontab like this could do: `0 14 * * SUN ./my_script.py`

If you want to check when the next sunday 2-5PM will be, you can work something out with the `croniter` module. Here is an example:

```
c = croniter.croniter("0 14,15,16 * * SUN")
print c.get_next(datetime.datetime) # will output 2013-08-04 14:00:00
```

With the knowledge of when the next sunday 2PM will be, you can write a loop like this:

```
c = croniter.croniter("0 14 * * SUN")
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now > next_due_date:
        do_something()
        next_due_date = c.get_next(datetime.datetime)
        time.sleep(60 * 60 * 36)
    else:
      time.sleep(60 * 60 * 2) # sleep 2 hours
```

Comment: Yes, that with the now.weekday() (value between 0 and 6, so you want it to be 6 on a Sunday) should do the trick!

Comment: could you throw a 36 hour sleep at the end of that? im doing something Atm so i cant test the script right this moment but i really need it to wait 36 hour's before looping itself, essentially making sure that it doesnt play more then once that sunday

Comment: by i just want to thank you any information is truly essential to my progress and the growth of my education in general. i thoroughly enjoy dissecting these tidbits of scripts till i understand them :)

Comment: You're welcome :). I edited, so now it check for sunday 2PM, and when it "finds" it call `do_something` then wait for 36 hours, and will call `do_something` the next sunday at 2PM.